# How to skip blank cells with read_excel

Tags: r, readxl

I'm using read_excel to import data into R. Some of the cells in the excel file are empty. I want R to skip these, currently it is reading them into the variable as NA.

`file.dat <- read_excel("File.xlsx", sheet = 3)`

Alternatively, can read the data into another variable and remove the NA values, at that step?

`myData <-file.dat$MyData   #how do I skip NA when reading in the MyData variable?`

Snapshot of excel file:

[image]

Current output in R:

[image]
I'd like to remove the "NA's".  I don't need to retain the index.

Comment: What do you mean by "skip" exactly? Data frames in R are rectangular so each row has to have the same number of columns. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Right now it's unclear exactly what your data looks like and exactly what you want in R.

Comment: @Amarnath you want to delete entire rows with NA observation

Comment: @simar, I need to retain the other rows, just "skip" the blank cells, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myData <-file.dat$MyData  #read the variable`

`myData<-na.omit(myData) #remove the n/a`